# AngularJS + HammerJS + AngularUi: Using event passthrough

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, hammer.js

The following code is suppose to use AnguarUI's Event directive to pass through the HammerJS event but it doesn't work.  I'm obviously missing something but don't understand exactly what.  There are no errors thrown.

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="myapp"  charset="UTF-8">
    <head>
         <meta charset="utf-8"> 
         <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
         <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.5/angular.min.js"></script>
         <script type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.github.com/angular-ui/ui-utils/master/modules/event/event.js"></script>
         <script type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.github.com/EightMedia/hammer.js/v1.0.5/dist/hammer.min.js"></script>
         <style type="text/css">
            div {
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
            }
         </style>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="pageCtrl">
        <div ui-event="{ tap: 'tapCallback()' }"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            angular.module('myapp', ['ui.event']);
            function pageCtrl($scope) {
                $scope.tapCallback = function() {
                    alert("test");
                }
            }
         </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ui-events uses `elm.bind` to attach its listener.

Hammer.js doesn't have any dependencies, and by default it doesn't add itself to jQuery.
You can include a jQuery plugin to integrate both Hammer.js and jQuery together.

In the code you posted, you don't have that plugin. ( [here's a link to Hammer.js + jQuery Plugin](https://github.com/EightMedia/hammer.js/blob/master/dist/jquery.hammer.js) )

But then again, you don't even have jQuery in your page, and I'm not sure if that plugin works with angular's jqLite.

You can avoid all your problems by using [Angular Hammer](https://github.com/monospaced/angular-hammer) (**which you should be using**)
[Even the Hammer.js wiki links to it](http://github.com/EightMedia/hammer.js/wiki/Plugins)

Comment: `ui-event` does not require jQuery (nor does any of the ui-utils anymore. However, you still need to have jquery-events being emitted, so this is still a valid answer.